# Checking continuity of $f(x)=\ln(x)$

Tags: continuity

Is $f(x) = \ln e$ continuous on the domain $D= (0,e]$ given that $0$ is not being included in the domain?

Graphically, it seems to be continuous.

Comment: Yes, the question asked was the original one only. Can you please edit it back.

Comment: @LUCIFER Sorry for the wrong edit.

Answer (score 2):

This function is a constant function; since $\ln e$ is another name for $1$, your function could be written 
$$
f(x) = 1.
$$
Is *that* function continuous on the domain $(0, e]$? Sure. It's a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

It's a continuous function because easy to prove that for all $a>0$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\ln{x}=\ln{a}$$